# Increase filesystem mounted on /home/jupyter in Google Compute Engine

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disk, disk-partitioning

I'm working on a Google Compute Engine instance (through the Notebook instance in AI Platform).

I'm running a disk-intensive job (Neo4J on docker) and I've decided to both increase the root disk and attach another one.

When I run `df -h`, this is what I see:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            119G     0  119G   0% /dev
tmpfs            24G  8.7M   24G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       985G   13G  932G   2% /
tmpfs           119G     0  119G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           119G     0  119G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      124M  5.7M  119M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb         98G   62M   98G   1% /home/jupyter
```

And when I run `sudo lsblk`, this is what I see:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  1000G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0 999.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0     3M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   124M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0  1000G  0 disk /home/jupyter
```

As you can see I have 2 disks each of size 1000G. Anyway, even if `sdb` has size 1000G, just `98G` seem available for use and this causes my job to crash.

Is there anyway I can increase that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Logical Volume manager in Linux, you can increase the size of the file system.

> Logical Volume Manager (LVM) is used in Linux to manage hard drives
> and other storage devices. As the name implies, it can sort raw
> storage into logical volumes, making it easy to configure and use.
> [link](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager)

**Before using LVM to increase the size of your Filesystem [please consider](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP2/html/SLES-all/cha-resize-fs.html#sec-resize-fs-guidelines-increase):**

> You can grow a file system to the maximum space available on the
> device, or specify an exact size. Ensure that you grow the size of the
> device or logical volume before you attempt to increase the size of
> the file system.
>
> When specifying an exact size for the file system, ensure that the new
> size satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - The new size must be greater than the size of the existing data;    otherwise, data loss occurs.
> - The new size must be equal to or less than the current device size    because the file system size cannot extend beyond the space
>   available.

**To resize the File system:**

The size of a Btrfs file system can be changed by using the **btrfs filesystem resize**

```
sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /mnt
```

The size of an XFS file system can be increased by using the **xfs_growfs** command

```
sudo xfs_growfs -d /mnt
```

The size of Ext2, Ext3, and Ext4 file systems can be increased by using the **resize2fs** command

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

In this link, you can find more information about [Resizing file Systems](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP2/html/SLES-all/cha-resize-fs.html#sec-resize-fs-guidelines-increase).

Comment: On GCP Workbench notebook "sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb" did the trick. Even without the sudo password.

Answer (score 1):

The disk **sdb** is 1,000 GB, but the file system placed on that disk is 98 GB. The simplest solution is to copy the data from that disk and reformat it with a larger file system.